# AngularJS - How to update data in the View using a Service?

Tags: angularjs

I'll explain what I have so far. I have two `controllers` which are both using a `movieService` I have created which fetches a list of movies. The controllers are like this:

```
app.controller('MovieCtrl', ['$scope', 'movieService', function($scope, movieService) {

  $scope.movieService = movieService;

}]);

app.controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', 'movieService', function($scope, movieService) {

  $scope.movieService = movieService;

}]);
```

My Service looks like this:

```
app.service('movieService', ['$http', function($http) {
        var movie = undefined;
        var relatedMovies = undefined;
        var searchTerm = undefined;

        this.update = function(search) {
            searchTerm = search;
            fetch();
        };

        function fetch() {
            $http.get(/* some http call that puts data into movie */);

            $http.get(/* some http call that puts data into relatedMovies */);
        };

}]);
```

And my related view code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchTerm" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1500}" ng-change="movieService.update(searchTerm)">

<h1>{{ movieService.movie.Title }}</h1>
```

So on my view I have a search bar that when submitting the search term will use `movieService.update(searchTerm)`, which is working fine because I can log the output from `fetch()` to console and it will show me the movie data.

Inside the `movie` variable there is a `Title` variable, so right now, I am using `{{ movieService.movie.Title }}` to try and display the title of the movie in the view. The problem is that the `$scope.movieService` data is not updated in real time, so if I run a new search within the `service`, the data in the view will not be updated unless I manually do it. When the data in `movieService` is updated, the view should be too.

So here comes my question, how would I make sure that these `$scope.movieService` variables in the `controllers` are always up-to-date with the `service`? Should I use `$watch` or something like that? What is the best way to achieve this?

Update: Added CodePen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdMxaZ

Comment: Where is your html view? The part that is actually showing the data?

Comment: I'll add that to the OP now @cerd

Comment: In what way do you need to manually update the data in the view for it to work?

Comment: Also it doesn't appear that your fetch function is actually returning the $http.get results - or that you have any other way of actually getting the data back to the controller.

Comment: Well you can see that the view is displaying the movie title, and the search bar is simply running `update` to update the movie data in the service. So in practical terms, if I run a new search in the search bar, I would like the movie title (and other information) to update in the view. If I search for "The Avengers", it would update the movie data in the service to this movie, and the controllers/view would in turn see that it has changed and update the view to show information about "The Avengers". Hope I was clear @skeggse

Comment: @cerd I commented out that part, but the `$http.get` inside `fetch` is fetching the data and putting inside the `movie` and `relatedMovies` variables.

Comment: @germainelol That's what I figured. Based on what code you've posted, I would expect that this would work fine. Can you try making an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @skeggse So assigning the service to `$scope.movieService` should update the view when a new search is ran? I will try to get a demo up.

Comment: @skeggse I have added a CodePen demo. You can see from the alert message that the data is being fetched, but it is not showing in `movieService.movie.Title`

Comment: Have you tried using $watch?

Comment: He shouldn't need $watch or anything - it is unnecessary if he sets up the binding's properly. Shouldn't be exposing the service directly in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `movie` variable is just a variable in a service. Nothing about being a variable in a service grants the variable special powers. In order to see that variable in your controller, you need to make it part of the service itself. The service is just an object, and that's what you add your `update` function to. You need to make your `movie` and `relatedMovies` variables part of the service object.

Here's one way to solve this problem. The `movieData` object is just one way to solve this problem. Either way, you need to be changing the value of an object field as opposed to the value of a **local** variable.

```
app.service('movieService', function($http) {
    var movieData = {
        movie: undefined,
        relatedMovies: undefined
    };

    var searchTerm = undefined;

    movieData.update = function(search) {
        // searchTerm is fine because you're not trying to access it from the
        // controller
        searchTerm = search;
        fetch();
    };

    this.movieData = movieData;

    function fetch() {
        $http.get(/* movieData.movie = http data */);
        $http.get(/* movieData.relatedMovies = http data */);
    };
});


app.controller('MovieCtrl', [function($scope, movieService) {
  $scope.movieService = movieService.movieData;
});

app.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, movieService) {
  $scope.movieService = movieService.movieData;
});
```

You can also set a variable to the value of `this` in the service function and change the value of `movie` and `relatedMovies` on that variable.

```
app.service('movieService', function($http) {
    var movieService = this;
    // modifying this modifies movieService and vice-versa
    this.movie = undefined;
    this.relatedMovies = undefined;

    var searchTerm = undefined;

    this.update = function(search) {
        // searchTerm is fine because you're not trying to access it from the
        // controller
        searchTerm = search;
        fetch();
    };

    function fetch() {
        $http.get(/* movieService.movie = http data */);
        $http.get(/* movieService.relatedMovies = http data */);
    };
});


app.controller('MovieCtrl', [function($scope, movieService) {
  $scope.movieService = movieService;
});

app.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, movieService) {
  $scope.movieService = movieService;
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. So the trick is to make sure that `this.movieData` is holding the data so that the controllers can access it using `movieService.movieData`. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. The trick is to have the data in an object (any object) that both contexts can access. `$rootScope` would have accomplished that goal, but doing so violates best-practices.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that this code could be much cleaner, I always refer people to John Papas angular style guide - it makes this problem non-existent https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#resolving-promises-for-a-controller

Comment: @skeggse So it works just because it's inside an object using `{}`?

Comment: @cerd Yeah, that's what I was mentioning in the second paragraph when I said "You can also set a variable to the value of this in the service function and change the value of movie". @germainelol it works because it's in an object. The fact that I made an object using `{}` is of little consequence. I'll update my answer with an alternate example, but the bottom line is that in your `fetch` function you need to be changing the value of a field in an object, and not the value of a local variable.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'll implement the second example based on what you and @cerd said.

Comment: It is fine to use the value of a local variable, if you had for instance a fetchMovie function that returns that local variable.

Answer (score -1):

I usually store data in $rootScope so if you put the search result in $rootScope it will refresh real-time.

another method is to call the broadcast $rootScope.$broadcast(name, args)
which is not really practical

Comment: I'm not sure I want to use `$rootScope`, I'm trying to make sure that everything is done in an efficient, secure way. I'm trying not to start putting things in the `$rootScope` first.

Comment: This is not best practice, it violates the entire dogma of separating controller scopes.